# D3 Create table from csv file that has multiple columns and NO HEADERS

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to display data from a multi-column csv (THAT DOES NOT HAVE HEADERS) in an html table. I've scoured the net for an answer but I don' think one exists.  Perhaps one does and I've missed it, but please don't just refer me to some post on the web because I've tried all of them and I'm still stuck.  Every example I've seen either has headers or is a single column.  Again, my csv file DOES NOT HAVE HEADERS and has multiple columns.  It looks like this.

```
2.051392,2.045899

2.04834,2.049256

2.051697,2.053833
```

So, as stated all over the internet, I'm passing the d3.csv.parserows function into the d3.text function. I then assign column names to the header row. All is fine until I assign data to the td elements. The code produces td elements that have column attributes of "ch1" and "ch2", yet the value attribute of the td element returns undefined. When I replace row[column] with row[0] or row[1], the value attribute returns a value, so I know the data is there.  What am I missing?

So in other words

```
value: row[column] //returns a value of undefined
value: row[0] //returns the first value in the row as expected
value: row[1] //returns the second value in the row as expected
```

I don't understand why row[column] doesn't return a value

```
function tab_data(data,columns)
{
var table = d3.select("#tabulatedData").append("table").attr("border","1"),
thead = table.append("thead"),
tbody = table.append("tbody");

// append the header row
thead.append("tr")
.selectAll("th")
.data(columns)
.enter()
.append("th")
.text(function(column) { return column; });

// create a row for each object in the data
rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("tr");

// Create a cell in each row for each column
var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
.data(function(row) {
return columns.map(function(column) {

return {
column: column,
value: row[column]
}; 

});
})
.enter()
.append("td")
.html(function(d) {

return d.value;

});




//main function

window.onload = function()

{
d3.text("data.csv", function(unparsedData)
{

data = d3.csv.parseRows(unparsedData);

tab_data(data,["ch1","ch2"]); 

});

}
```

I got it to work by editing the code as follows, although there has got to be a more elegant solution.  I thought the benefit of d3 was that the for loop was a thing of the past.

```
// Create a cell in each row for each column
var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {

            for(var i = 0; i<columns.length; i++)
            {
                row[columns[i]] = row[i];
            }

            return {
                column: column,
                value: row[column]
            };  

        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .html(function(d) {

        return d.value;

    });
```

Comment: Where are you assigning names to the columns? I don't see anything in the code you've posted that does that.

Comment: When I call the tab_data() function in my main program, I pass column names "ch1" and "ch2".  This array of names called columns is then used in the tab_data() function to assign each column a name.  Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I'm looking for something like `row[column] = row[index]`. Where specifically are you assigning the headers?

Comment: I thought I was doing it with the code underneath the //append the header row comment. No?  Doesn't that code iterate through each value in the columns array and assign a header?

Comment: You're modifying the DOM there, not the data.

Comment: Thanks.  I added a for loop that assigns headers just before I return the column and value attributes and it works.

Comment: Great, could you post that as an answer please for reference?

Comment: Please see my edited post.  Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: As long as it solves your problem. I agree that it's not particularly pretty, but then again D3 isn't really meant for low-level data manipulation like that.